# How to declare Global variable in spring boot Application

Tags: spring-data-jpa, global-variables

I am trying to develop micro service by using spring boot. Project containing multiple services end point. In every endpoint I am declaring  `@CrossOrigin("")`. Can I declare that variable in `Application.property` file? or any other way to declare that variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a bean like this to configure CORS(cross origin) settings globally.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(final CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("*").allowedOrigins("your_host");
  }
}
```

There are many methods and options which you can configure.

Comment: can you give reference link

Comment: where I need to add this configuration file

Comment: You can add it anywhere in your project. It doesnt  matter